# jQuery: Stopping a periodic ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a small jQuery plugin to update a set of Divs with content obtained using Ajax calls. Initially, let's assume we have 4 divs. I am doing something like this:

```
(function($) {
    ....
    ....

    //main function
    $.fn.jDIV = {
       init: function() {
          ...
          ...
          for(var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
             this.query(i);
          }
          this.handlers();
       },

       query: function(divNum) {
          //Makes the relevant ajax call
       },

       handlers: function() {
          for(var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
            setInterval("$.fn.jDIV.query(" + i + ")", 5000);
          }
       }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I would like to be able to enable and disable a particular ajax query. I was thinking of adding a "start" and "stop" instead of the "handlers" function and subsequently storing the setInterval handler like this:

```
start: function(divNum) {
    divs[divNum] = setInterval("$.fn.jDIV.query(" + divNum + ")", 5000);
},
stop: function(divNum) {
    clearInterval(divs[divNum]);
}
```

I did not use jQuery to setup and destroy the event handlers. Is there a better approach (perhaps using more of jQuery) to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't pass a string to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`!, give it an anonymous function instead...for example try your code with `.noConflict()`, it'll break, because it actually depends on `$` being jQuery when that interval executes.   If you pass a function you can properly use `this.query(i);`, just be sure to pass `i` into the closure.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Thanks. Will change that.

Comment: @Nick Craver: When I pass an anonymous function and substitute with this.query(i), it complains that this.query is not a function. Can you please tell me if I missing something here? I am using: ``setInterval(function() { this.query(i); }, 5000);``

Comment: You need to pass `this` into the closure as well, or use `$.proxy()`, either way, here's the non-proxy method (look at the console for output): http://jsfiddle.net/YkjwK/